# User Account Control and outside processes

Tags: network, windows, remote-desktop

I was using [TeamViewer](http://www.teamviewer.com) (a remote desktop client) to log in to a remote computer running Windows 7.

While logged in, the Java updater prompted me for administrator access to run an update check. Out of habit, I pressed <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd> (for "Yes") to grant the updater permission. This worked, and the updater ran.

However, doesn't this entirely defeat the purpose of User Account Control? Much like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Delete</kbd>, isn't it supposed to *prevent* programs from providing input? Why was TeamViewer able to trick UAC into thinking that I was physically at the terminal pressing the keys?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When teamviewer is installed it includes a daemon that runs under the system account. The client that is started under the users account only provides instructions to this daemon.

As this service already has elevated rights assigned at the time of installation (the creation of this daemon) it is possible to directly emulate key strokes as coming from the local system.

Comment: So it wouldn't be possible to install such a daemon without administrator rights? i.e., at some point in the chain of installations, the user actually has to approve it manually?

Comment: @WChargin - correct